# Cytoscape: Avoid overlapping grouping nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there a layout or an option to avoid grouping nodes to overlap eachother?
I'm getting a graph with standalone and grouped nodes, but the combinations are dependent on dynamic data. So i can not place them on my one, or would like to avoid it. 
All layouts i have tried do not take care of the grouping nodes and place their sub nodes together.
For example 'circle' creates one circle of all nodes, not a circle per group.

The goal would be to create something like "http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/5b192c88616af2f75344/", but there the nodes are placed manualy..

I have seen the example "http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/59e38e9f20e25a293e44/" which seems to work as required but it is using an extension. First of all i would like to find a built in solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement for a non-extension solution is erroneous.

Only basic, small KB layouts are included in Cytoscape.js itself, and it makes no functional difference whether a layout is included by default or not:  [They are both extensions](http://js.cytoscape.org/#architecture) -- some are included by default, some are not.

[CoSE Bilkent](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent) is the best compound node layout algorithm for graphs/networks -- bar none.  You can alternatively use CoSE, which is included by default.  [CoSE](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/cose) is a more basic version of the algorithm, optimised for speed at the expense of visual results in some cases.

Comment: True, that is also descripted by the documentation. But, for me, there is a difference. If a framework has an extension posibility and is delivered with some "built in" extensions, this extensions will be updated and maintained with the framework. For 3rd party extensions it is even more probably that they are not. Thats why I want to avoid them... if possible!

Comment: Many extensions, including CoSE Bilkent are first party.  It's under the same Cytoscape Consortium group on Github.  Third party extensions are not under this group.